# Parse string value into integer during MongoDB find query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, nosql-aggregation

I need to be able to parse deeply nested string value to be able to find an amount greater than in my request query. I fount that $expr operator is supposed to help in that, but when i try to implement it it gives me

> "message" : "unknown operator: $expr",

here is my code:

```
db.OrderAttributes.find({
    InfluencedAttributes: {$elemMatch: {
        LexisAttributes:{$elemMatch: {
            $expr: { $gt: [ {$toDouble: "$MyAttributes.MyField"}, 500]}
        }}
    }}
}
```

the value I'm trying to compare is here

```
InfluencedAttributes.0.LexisAttributes.0.MyAttributes.MyField = "20000"
```

trimmed version of the lookup document:

```
db.OrderAttributes.insertOne({
    "InfluencedAttributes" : [
        {
            "LexisAttributes" : [
                {
                    "MyAttributes" : {
                        "MyValue" : "20000"
                    }
                },
                {
                    ...
                },
                {
                    ...
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}})
```

Comment: Hi, could you add a sample document?

Comment: @HanielBaez added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$expr` is not a valid query for `$elemMatch`, but you still have two way to achive the desire result:

**First option:**

```
db.OrderAttributes.find({"$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$toDouble": "$InfluencedAttributes.0.LexisAttributes.0.MyAttributes.MyField"}, 500 ] } } );
```

Performance: COLLSCAN for a collection scan.

**Second option:**

```
db.OrderAttributes.find({ "InfluencedAttributes.0.LexisAttributes.0.MyAttributes.MyField": {$regex: /^([5-9]\d{2,}|\d{4,})/ } } );
```

Performance: IXSCAN for scanning index keys.